# How to replace an element in a list that was randomly picked and removed in python?

Tags: python

I have a text and it splits the string per dot; list= s.split("."). I convert it to the list as shown and remove one string randomly. And I need to replace the removed string with '[1]', how to make it? 
my code is here:

```
s = input("Enter a text here: ")
list= s.split(".")
import random
x = random.choice(list)
print(x)
parts.remove(x)
print(list)
listToString = ".".join([str(i) for i in list])
print(listToString)
```

Comment: no need to remove just replace `list[list.index(x)]  = 1`

Comment: @komatiraju032 - assuming no repeats in the string

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to replace the item, use a random integer as selector instead of `random.choice`. There are a few other ways to tidy your script (for instance, for posted test script, a canned string may help us lazy commentators)

```
import random

#s = input("Enter a text here: ")
s = "one.two.three.four"
mylist = s.split(".")
i = random.randint(0, len(mylist)-1)
print(mylist[i])
mylist[i] = '[1]'
print(mylist)
listToString = ".".join(str(i) for i in mylist)
print(listToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest way but it works if the elements are unique:

```
s = input("Enter a text here: ")
slist = s.split(".")
import random
x = random.choice(slist)
slist[slist.index(x)] = '[1]'
listToString = '.'.join([str(i) for i in slist])
print(listToString)
```

Output:

```
Enter a text here: foo.bar
[1].bar
```